# Display distinct list from MongoDB using c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following document structure in mongoDb:

[image: mongoDB document structure]

I want to query it from an asp.net C# app using linq.  I would like a distinct list of all the t values.  If I run this code I get a list of t values for all of my documents and the value of t is repeated over documents.

```
var query = from m in collection.AsQueryable()
                        select m.t;
```

I therefore want a distinct list of t.  I amended my code to the following but nothing is returned and there is no error message.

```
var query = (from p in collection.AsQueryable()
                        select p.t).Distinct();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The thing is that `Distinct()` returns `IQueryable<T>` which represents the database operation. To materialize that you need to run `.ToList()`, the rest of your code is fine, try:

```
var query = (from p in collection.AsQueryable()
                    select p.t).Distinct();
var data = query.ToList();
```

Comment: this answer is actually right, BsonDocument already implements IEquatable<BsonDocument>

Comment: @mickl - thanks.  Is there anyway to speed it up as its been well over a minute and its still populating data.  My db has over 3 million documents and there are approx 3000 distinct values of t.

Comment: @Silentbob do you have an index on "t" field ?

Comment: @mickl yes i do

Comment: @Silentbob then I suppose you need to cache this distinct list somehow, maybe in-memory, maybe in a separate collection that can be recalculated periodically